Need help parsing the list of people
From Kakegurui volume 1 あとがき:

「賭ケグルイ」の執筆にあたって、たくさんの方にお世話になっています。緻密かつ大胆、可愛らしさと迫力の同居する作画により、「賭ケグルイ」を僕の脳内イメージを遥かに超える漫画に仕立てあげて下さっている尚村先生、アシスタントの方々をはじめ、僕の稚拙なネームの改善点を指摘し漫画の完成度を上げ、また秀逸な煽り、サブタイトルを提供して下さる等、あらゆる面で世話になっている担当の佐々木様、湯本様。アシスタントをしたことで、僕が漫画業界に興味を持つきっかけをくれた友人、漫画家の武中英雄君。

You can see that the author is listing many people he worked with. I have difficulty figuring out the structure of this chunky paragraph. It appears to me he is thanking 6 (maybe 5?) people in total:

尚村先生
尚村先生's assistants
担当の佐々木様
湯本様 (not sure if he's also 担当)
武中英雄君
友人 (probably refers to 武中英雄君?)

I initially thought XXXをはじめ here is used to give an example of people who does 僕の稚拙なネームの改善点を指摘し漫画の完成度を上げ、また秀逸な煽り、サブタイトルを提供して下さる but I now think it is used to give an example of people who he feels thankful to.
Did I parse everything correctly?

I think you're correct! ～をはじめ is used to introduce the first example  of たくさんの方にお世話になっています.
［緻密かつ大胆、可愛らしさと迫力の同居する作画により、「賭ケグルイ」を僕の脳内イメージを遥かに超える漫画に仕立てあげて下さっている］
→ ①尚村先生 and ②アシスタントの方々
［僕の稚拙なネームの改善点を指摘し漫画の完成度を上げ、また秀逸な煽り、サブタイトルを提供して下さる等、あらゆる面で世話になっている]
→ ③担当の佐々木様 and ④担当の湯本様
［アシスタントをしたことで、僕が漫画業界に興味を持つきっかけをくれた］
→ ⑤友人＝漫画家の武中英雄君

Thank you again!
